# How can I make this login system work? (Tkinter-python)

Tags: python, tkinter, logging

The ***user_entry*** and ***pass_entry*** are just input boxes. Menu function just shows a canvas (blue with text). ***It only works with the last username and password***

The text file is just like this:

user1|password1

name1|password2

```
def login():
    global user_entry, pass_entry, password
    
    user = user_entry.get()
    with open("Users and passwords.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for item in lines:
            data = item.split("|")
            for i in range(0, 2):
                if data[i] == user:
                    password = data[i+1]
                    check_pass()
    
def check_pass():
    password_v = pass_entry.get()
    if password_v == password:
        menu()
```

Comment: You need to break the outer for loop when user and password are found.  Actually the inner for loop is not necessary.

Comment: `readlines` gives lines with `\n` at the end (except last line if there is no next line in file) and you may have to `strip()` it because you may compare `"password" == "password\n"` and one of them has `'\n'`

Comment: first youc oould use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables (and also `print( password_v == password )`). It is called `'print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you should rather run function which only check user, password and returns `True/False`. You runs `menu()` in `check_pass()` which runs in `for-loops - and when `menu()` finish work then it will back to `check_pass()` which will back to `for`-loops and it will check next users and password - but you don't need it.